# Attaching / Sending .ics event via email in php

Tags: php, email-attachments, icalendar

I am having trouble trying to send an .ics file 'meeting invitation' via email.

I am using this class to quickly generate the contents of the .ics file:
https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416

The content generates correctly but I cannot get it to show as an attachment... so far only as string.

I have even tried to encode it but it just shows the encoded .ics content as a string.

Here is my code currently:

```
// CREATE ICAL INVITE
include("ICS.php");

//header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=cita.ics');

$location = "Barcelona";
$mdesc = "Cita Masaje";
$mname= "$name - $phone";
$meetURL = "redacted";

$props = array(
    'location' => $location,
    'description' => $mdesc,
    'dtstart' => $dateStart,
    'dtend' => $dateEnd,
    'summary' => $mname,
    'url' => $meetURL
);

$ics = new ICS($props);
$ical = $ics->to_string();
$boundary = md5("random"); // define boundary with a md5 hashed value

$recipient = "redacted";
$subject = "Nuevo contacto de $name - $email";
//header
$mailheaders = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: ".$name." <".$email.">\n";
$mailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$mailheaders .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
$mailheaders .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n"; //Defining the Boundary

//attachment
$formcontent = "--$boundary\r\n";
$formcontent .= "De: $name - $email\nTel: $phone\nCita: $dateStart\nAcaba: $dateEnd\nMensaje:\n\n$message\n\n";

$formcontent .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($ical));

$formcontent .="Content-Disposition: attachment";
$formcontent .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
//$formcontent .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
//$formcontent .='Content-Type: text/calendar; name="cita.ics"; method=REQUEST\n';
$formcontent .="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name='cita.ics'; method=REQUEST\n";
$formcontent .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\n";
$formcontent .= $encoded_content; // Attaching the encoded file with email

// Send email notification
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheaders)) {
    // send auto-reply
    mail($email, $rplysubject, $reply, $rplyheader) or die("Error!");
} else {
    die("Error!");
}
echo "Muchas gracias $name! Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.";
```

Commented out are some of the things I have tried... below is the current result from the autoreply email:

```
boundary = 7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509

--7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509
De: Testuser - test@mail.com
Tel: 654396757
Cita: 21-04-2021 10:00
Acaba: 21-04-2021 11:00
Mensaje:

test message

--7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509
Content-Disposition: attachmentContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name='cita.ics'; method=REQUEST
X-Attachment-Id: 8311
QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KUFJPRElEOi0vL2hhY2tzdy9oYW5kY2FsLy9O
T05TR01MIHYxLjAvL0VODQpDQUxTQ0FMRTpHUkVHT1JJQU4NCkJFR0lOOlZFVkVOVA0KTE9DQVRJ
T046QmFyY2Vsb25hDQpERVNDUklQVElPTjpDaXRhIE1hc2FqZQ0KRFRTVEFSVDoyMDIxMDQyMVQx
MDAwMDBaDQpEVEVORDoyMDIxMDQyMVQxMTAwMDBaDQpTVU1NQVJZOktpbGxpbm15dmliZXogLSA2
NTQzOTY3NTcNClVSTDtWQUxVRT1VUkk6aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGltZTJtZS5lcw0KRFRTVEFNUDoy
MDIxMDQxNVQxMzMzMjJaDQpVSUQ6NjA3ODI0ODI0Y2Y0MQ0KRU5EOlZFVkVOVA0KRU5EOlZDQUxF
TkRBUg==
```

In the past I also tried mail->addAttachment() or ->addStringAttachment() but both of those calls break my code.

Here is what the non-encoded ics event looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:Barcelona
DESCRIPTION:Cita
DTSTART:20210428T090000Z
DTEND:20210428T100000Z
SUMMARY:Testuser - 672346435
URL;VALUE=URI:https://www.redacted.com
DTSTAMP:20210409T221423Z
UID:6070b59fe043d
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any idea what the issue could be?? Many thanks ahead of time!

Comment: To save yourself a lot of headache, I would recommend that you use one of the tried and tested mail libraries, like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer or similar instead. They are much easier to use than the low level `mail()`-function (which I'm assuming your using, even if you haven't posted how you're actually sending the mail).

Comment: Please share more details - how do you actually send the mail?

Comment: Thank you Magnus, I had also tried attaching it with PHPMailer having included PHPMailer.php & Exception.php but that did not seem to work correctly. I guess I can´t use ONLY the attachment part of PHPMailer while sending it with regular mail.php

Perhaps I will go back and retry with PHPMailer substituting the entire mail creation, attaching and sending process.

Comment: The mail send function has been included. There are 2 emails being sent, but the relevant one is the first one, which needs to include the .ics file.
I´ve also included the ics contents before encoding.

I am quite lost as to what is failing here... many of the examples online simply append the .ics contents to the email mesage... some of them are using this MIME thing that I need to find out more about, some of the examples say to base64 encode it, some say that you need to puttofile the ics contents than attach that file... not sure which way to go.

Comment: Why not use any library that already knows how to build mails? This is not a simple task if you want to use attachments

Comment: Does anybody have experience generating and sending .ics events via php?

Comment: @Nico Haase Neither of the suggested posts clearly answers the question, however I will attempt once more using PHPMailer and report back if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly answers which question? Whether anyone has "experience generating and sending .ics events via php"? How do these code snippets not show that others have tried that?

Comment: I´m not here to argue and SO policy states no discussions are to be had in the comments, only in chat. Regardless, neither of the questions you´ve cited have been officially answered. The first is not regarding attaching the event, but actually about getting certain options (RSVP buttons) to show to the recipient. The organizer & attendee fields aren´t actually required just to send an ICS event. The second question you´ve cited only has suggestions to use PHPMailer. I will attempt to follow this guide: https://blog.webnersolutions.com/how-to-send-ical-attachment-via-phpmailer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up implementing PHPMailer and it worked liked a charm.